# Use style in a single node depending of the style of its parent matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, pgfkeys, styles

I have the following TikZ snippet that renders some selected nodes in a matrix:

```
\tikzset{
    red/.style={ nodes={font=\large} },
    blue/.style={ nodes={font=\small} },
    special red/.style={ text=red },
    special blue/.style={ text=blue },
}

\matrix[red] {
    \node {normal node 1}; &
    \node [special red] {special red node}; &
    \node {normal node 2}; \\
};

\tikzset{yshift=-1cm}

\matrix[blue] {
    \node {normal node 1}; &
    \node {normal node 2}; &
    \node [special blue] {special blue node} ;\\
};
```

[image]

But I want to achieve the same result by using only the `special` style in nodes and delegating on the type of matrix how those special nodes are rendered. Something like:

```
\tikzset{
    ...
}

\matrix[red] {
    \node {normal node 1}; &
    \node [special] {special red node}; &
    \node {normal node 2}; \\
};

\tikzset{yshift=-1cm}

\matrix[blue] {
    \node {normal node 1}; &
    \node {normal node 2}; &
    \node [special] {special blue node} ;\\
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `.is choice` key can do the trick:

```
\tikzset{
    red/.style={
        nodes={
            special/.default=red,
            font=\large
        }
    },
    blue/.style={
        nodes={
            special/.default=blue,
            font=\small
        }
    },
    special/.is choice,
    special/red/.style={ text=green },
    special/blue/.style={ text=blue },
}

\matrix[red] {
    \node {normal node 1}; &
    \node [special] {special red node}; &
    \node {normal node 2}; \\
};

\tikzset{yshift=-1cm}

\matrix[blue] {
    \node {normal node 1}; &
    \node {normal node 2}; &
    \node [special] {special blue node} ;\\
};
```